# How to get <select> value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get value from  and send it through php? It's okay with text input but I can't get  value. I just need to send values through email via ajax and php.

html code

```
<div class="input">
<input type="text" name="height" placeholder=""/>
</div>
    <div class="input">
        <select name="select">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <select name="selectt">
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

js code

```
var user_height = $(this).find("input[name='height']").val();

var user_select = $(this).find("input[name='select']").val();
var user_selectt = $(this).find("input[name='selectt']").val();
var ok_send = $(this).find('.results_send_form');
//getting values
$.ajax({
    url: "send.php",
    type: "post", 
    dataType: "json", 
    data: { 
        "height": user_height,
        "select": user_select,
        "selectt": user_selectt,
    }
```

Comment: What does `$(this)` belong to? What is triggering the script and have you checked the browser console for errors or use it for debugging? Also where is the input with the name `selectt`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
var user_height = $(this).find("input[name='height']").val();
var user_select = $(this).find("input[name='select']").val();
var user_selectt = $(this).find("input[name='selectt']").val();
```

to

```
var user_height = $(this).find("input[name='height']:selected").val();
var user_select = $(this).find("input[name='select']:selected").val();
var user_selectt = $(this).find("input[name='selectt']:selected").val();
```

Comment: What would this accomplish?  The value of a select menu is already what is selected.  There also can't be a selected input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an input named `select` or `selectt`, these are select menus.  I don't know what `this` refers to in your code since you  didn't include the context, but you would need to use `select[name='select']` or `select[name='selectt']`.